# Blazor: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, blazor

I am creating an app in Blazor, upon getting a list of data displayed(Index View) I am running into the following error:

```
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

I have heard that Blazor does not support HttpClient for Injection. So I wrote a custom HttpClient to do the same job, however I ran into an issue and unable to understand why I am getting it.

Below is a copy of my entity section:

```
public class Tournament
    {
        [Key]
        public int TournamentID { get; set; }
        public string TournamentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

A copy of my code section in razor page:

```
@code {
    Tournament[] tournaments;
    string baseUrl;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        baseUrl = AppSettingsService.GetBaseUrl();
        tournaments = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Tournament[]>(baseUrl + "api/tournaments/gettournaments");
    }
}
```

And a copy of my custom http client class:

```
public async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(string requestUri)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var httpContent = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
            string jsonContent = httpContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent);
            httpContent.Dispose();
            httpClient.Dispose();
            return obj;
        }
```

Can anyone help me further in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use client-side Blazor or server-side Blazor ?

Comment: @enet Server side

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's what I have read from other posts, Do you know how I could accomplish this?